# recv function not receive all bytes

Tags: sockets, delphi

I'm using delphi (RAD Studio 10) to make a little app client and server. The server only send text.

The next functions returns correctly the number of bytes sent. For example I send 'hello' (client side):

```
procedure TTCPConnection.Write(S: String);
var buff : string;
begin
  buff = S+EOL;
  WriteBuffer(buff, Length(buff));
end;
```

Where: `S = 'hello'` and `EOL = #13#10`, so `buff = 'hello'+EOL`.

```
procedure TTCPConnection.WriteBuffer(var Buffer; const Len: Cardinal);
var
  a : Int16;
begin
  a :=  send(FSocket, Buffer, Len, 0);
  if (a = SOCKET_ERROR) and FConnected then
  begin
    HandleError;
    Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

in the previous function: `send(FSocket, Buffer, Len, 0)` return 7, number of bytes sent ('hello+EOL').

Server side:

```
function TTCPConnection.ReadLn(Delim: String = EOL): String;
const BUFFER_SIZE = 255;
var
  Buff, Buf: string;
  I, L: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  I := 1;
  L := 1;
  SetLength(Buff, BUFFER_SIZE);
  Buf := AnsiString(Buff);
  while Connected and (L <= Cardinal(Length(Delim))) do
  begin
    if recv(FSocket, Buffer, Len, 0) < 1 then exit;
    Buf := Buff[I];
    if Buff[I] = Delim[L] then
      ...
    ...
end;
```

(In the previous code I include `Buf` var for debugger purposes only). When I debug obtain this result:

`Buff = {'h', #0, 'e', #0, 'l', #0, 'l'}` (7 bytes) and the next time this line is executed `recv(FSocket, Buffer, Len, 0)` the program does nothing, I guess this is because recv function has nothing to receive (7 bytes were sent).

I need help to make all bytes are received correctly. I do not know why they are in that order (`h-#0-e-#0-l-#0-l`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with RAD Studio 2009, `string` consists of `WideChar` characters. `Char` is an alias for `WideChar` and is 16 bit. The `Length()` function returns number of characters, not bytes.

You may want to consider using `TEncoding` to convert your string to a `TBytes` (`array of byte`) for sending and vice versa for receiving. I don't know your `TTCPConnection` class, so it may be you need to tweek the code, but here for the sending part using `TEncoding.UTF8`:

```
procedure TTCPConnection.Write(S: String);
var buff : TBytes;
begin
  buff := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(S+EOL);  // Convert to bytes using UTF8 encoding
  WriteBuffer(buff, Length(buff));
end;
```

And here is my receiver code from a testproject in XE5 where I used the `TTcpServer` component

```
procedure TForm3.TcpServer1Accept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
var
  a: array[0..255] of byte;
  b: TBytes;
  i, n: integer;
  s: string;
begin
  n := ClientSocket.ReceiveBuf(a,255,0);
  SetLength(b, n);
  for i := Low(b) to High(b) do b[i] := a[i]; // copy from the receive buffer
  s := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(b);           // convert UTF8 bytes to string
  Memo1.Lines.Add(format('%4d %s',[n,s]));
end;
```

Finally a few useful links to the documentation:

[TEncoding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.TEncoding)

[UTF-8 Conversion Routines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/UTF-8_Conversion_Routines)

Comment: Thanks. now recv function gets full information `Buff = {'h', #0, 'e', #0, 'l', #0, 'l', #0, 'o' , '$D', #0, '$A'}`.Now, I must build a new Buffer without `#0`? or I'm doing something wrong, which is not shown as it should? (`Buff = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '$D', '$A'}`)

Comment: @Tom Neither of your options are good. With UTF16 you need to tackle endianness. If you want to avoid that use an 8 bit Unicode encoding, UTF8.

Comment: @Jota69 You need to stop sending text, and start thinking about encoding text as binary in a specific encoding. UTF8 is the best choice.

Comment: @Tom I am very grateful. You were very helpful

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, But I needed to understand the reason for that. Now I can continue to improve the code, thank you very much

Comment: @Jota coding is not what you need. Understanding of encodings should be your next move

Comment: @David You are right, I'll improve in a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. For now I working with pure WinApi and WinSock. Excellent information